# What is the main difference between Theta star algorithm and Phi star algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, path-finding

I'm trying to work on `Phi* algorithm` for pathfinding and I'm confused about it and the `Theta star`. I searched a lot, but there are no resources or codes to deal with it. What are the new points of the `Phi* algorithm` and How could I deal with it? Any guidance or resources for `Phi* algorithm`, please?

Answer (score 0):

Phi* is an incremental algorithm, meaning it recomputes the best path when the graph changes faster than running a different algorithm from scratch.

See [this cstheory.SE question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/11855/how-do-the-state-of-the-art-pathfinding-algorithms-for-changing-graphs-d-d-l) for more info.